# npm command to know utlities in a package

Tags: javascript, npm

While importing a package to my code, for example:

`import { Text, View, StyleSheet } from "react-native";`

How I can know the complete list of utilities functions like `Text`, `View` etc available in package `react-native` ?

Is there any npm command for this. I couldn't find any such list/docs in https://www.npmjs.com/package/react-native too.

Comment: You can find `react-native`'s full list of it's components in it's official documentations [here](https://reactnative.dev/docs/components-and-apis).<br>
Sadly, I don't know if there are any npm commands to do this with.

Comment: @MinekoKayui: Thank you for the reply. `react-native` here is just an example and for it documentation is available. What I am specifically looking is a npm command listing all exports possible from the package. Sadly it's not straight forward.

Comment: Ooh, I see, I dint quite understand the question clearly, sorry for the misunderstanding.

Answer (score 1):

You can't exactly run an npm command, because `npm` is a package manager for `node`, commands run in npm will be for package management, whereas commands run in `node` itself is what you need to get the utilities functions.

I did a lot of research on this and found one solution. What you want to do is, after installing the package you want to check on using `npm`, let's say it's `discord.js`:

```
npm install discord.js
```

Now, run node directly, no `index.js` or any other files required.

```
node
```

Then, use the following command:

```
Object.keys(require('discord.js'))
```

While in node, this will return a list of all it's utilities. Of course, this example was using `discord.js`, though it can be any npm packages with utility functions.

This should return something like:

```json
[
  'BaseClient',             'Client',                 'Shard',
  'ShardClientUtil',        'ShardingManager',        'WebhookClient',
  'ActivityFlags',          'BitField',               'Collection',
  'Constants',              'DataResolver',           'BaseManager',
  'DiscordAPIError',        'HTTPError',              'MessageFlags',
  'Intents',                'Permissions',            'Speaking',
  'Snowflake',              'SnowflakeUtil',          'Structures',
  'SystemChannelFlags',     'UserFlags',              'Util',
  'version',                'ChannelManager',         'GuildChannelManager',
  'GuildEmojiManager',      'GuildEmojiRoleManager',  'GuildMemberManager',
  'GuildMemberRoleManager', 'GuildManager',           'ReactionManager',
  'ReactionUserManager',    'MessageManager',         'PresenceManager',
  'RoleManager',            'UserManager',            'discordSort',
  'escapeMarkdown',         'fetchRecommendedShards', 'resolveColor',
  'resolveString',          'splitMessage',           'Base',
  'Activity',               'APIMessage',             'BaseGuildEmoji',
  'CategoryChannel',        'Channel',                'ClientApplication',
  'ClientUser',             'Collector',              'DMChannel',
  'Emoji',                  'Guild',                  'GuildAuditLogs',
  'GuildChannel',           'GuildEmoji',             'GuildMember',
  'GuildPreview',           'Integration',            'Invite',
  'Message',                'MessageAttachment',      'MessageCollector',
  'MessageEmbed',           'MessageMentions',        'MessageReaction',
  'NewsChannel',            'PermissionOverwrites',   'Presence',
  'ClientPresence',         'ReactionCollector',      'ReactionEmoji',
  'RichPresenceAssets',     'Role',                   'StoreChannel',
  'Team',                   'TeamMember',             'TextChannel',
  'User',                   'VoiceChannel',           'VoiceRegion',
  'VoiceState',             'Webhook',                'WebSocket'
]
```

Which is basically all the utility functions available in `discord.js`. Now, sometimes, you will run into this error:

```
SyntaxError: Cannot use import statement inside the Node.js REPL, alternatively use dynamic import
```

This is because I'm running it from `node` and not from a module or app. Then if you try it inside a non-module package, like a bot in `discord.js`, it will return this error:

```
SyntaxError: Cannot use import statement outside a module
```

These two errors above won't show up if you're making a module instead and calling import from inside the module.

---

This is because a `discord.js` bot isn't a module and if I force define module in the `package.json`, it will break. In this case, there's nothing you can do from inside, you can try to look up it's documentations or source code to find it yourself.

Here're some references to using this command:

- [Node js module how to get list of exported functions](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/25529290/node-js-module-how-to-get-list-of-exported-functions)
- [SyntaxError: Cannot use import statement outside a module](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/58384179/syntaxerror-cannot-use-import-statement-outside-a-module)
- [Error : Cannot use import statement outside a module in react native new project](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/60364691/error-cannot-use-import-statement-outside-a-module-in-react-native-new-project)

Comment: Thank you @Mineko for the detailed answer. Quite helpful.

Answer (score -1):

You could do this

```
import Rn from "react-native";

console.log(Object.keys(Rn));
```